# Calculator buttons are not working and giving "Not Defined" error message

Tags: python-3.x, button, tkinter, calculator

I'm writing a program by watching a tutorial and I have managed to arrange buttons correctly inside my calculator application and below the calculator screen display. Now when I try to click any button from the calculator, it shows an error message in the pycharm..

I have tried some alternate codes to make the buttons work and every other similiar question have whole different code for buttons and everything so I couldn't make mine work by getting help from the topics..they are different.. but none of them are working..

Code:

```
from tkinter import *

cal = Tk()
cal.title("Calculator New")

operator = ""

text_Input = StringVar()
txtDisplay = Entry(cal, font = ('comic sans ms', 20, 'bold', 'italic'),
 textvariable = text_Input, bd = 30, insertwidth = 4, bg ="Black", fg = "Red",
                justify ='right').grid(columnspan = 4)

btn7 = Button(cal, padx = 16, pady = 16, bd = 8, fg = "black", bg ="white", font = ('comic sans ms' , 10, 'bold',),
          text = "7", command = lambda:btnClick(7)).grid(row=1, column=0)

cal.mainloop()
```

expected :

When I click 7, the display should show 7.

Actual :

Button doesn't work and shows this error message in pycharm..

> NameError: name 'btnClick' is not defined

Comment: I sorted this out, I added a new function with the name btnClick and passed numbers and some kind of global operator.. thank you..

Comment: Post an answer for your question and choose it as a correct answer after 48 hours.

Answer (score 1):

You will need to define a function and assign it to the button:

```
def btnClick():
    number = btn7.cget('text')
    txtDisplay.insert(string=number, index=0)
```

And there is no need to add lambda. And you need to do:

```
btn7.grid(row=1, column=0)
```

instead of:

```
btn7 = Button(cal, padx = 16, pady = 16, bd = 8, fg = "black", bg ="white", font = ('comic sans ms' , 10, 'bold',), text = "7", command = lambda:btnClick(7)).grid(row=1, column 
=0)
```

Because it throws tons of errors when you do that.

### Full Code:

```
from tkinter import *

def btnClick():
    number = btn7.cget('text')
    txtDisplay.insert(string=number, index=0)

cal = Tk()

cal.title("Calculator New")

operator = ""

text_Input = StringVar()
txtDisplay = Entry(cal, font=('comic sans ms', 20, 'bold', 'italic'), textvariable = text_Input, bd = 30, insertwidth = 4, bg ="Black", fg = "Red", justify ='right')
txtDisplay.grid(columnspan = 4)

btn7 = Button(cal, padx = 16, pady = 16, bd = 8, fg = "black", bg ="white", font = ('comic sans ms' , 10, 'bold',), text = "7", command=btnClick)
btn7.grid(row=1, column=0)

cal.mainloop()
```

Welcome To StackOverflow!